# Julia: cannot assign a value to variable Base.! from module StaticArrays

Tags: julia

I am trying to install Plots package on Julia. Window 10.

```
using Plots
```

Full error:

```
[ Info: Precompiling Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80]
ERROR: LoadError: cannot assign a value to variable Base.! from module StaticArrays

ERROR: LoadError: Failed to precompile GeometryBasics [5c1252a2-5f33-56bf-86c9-59e7332b4326] to C:\Users\Vladimir\.julia\compiled\v1.7\GeometryBasics\jl_DDF.tmp.

ERROR: Failed to precompile Plots [91a5bcdd-55d7-5caf-9e0b-520d859cae80] to C:\Users\Vladimir\.julia\compiled\v1.7\Plots\jl_D09.tmp.
```

How to deal with it and install the package?

Comment: What does `using code` mean?

Comment: Sorry, I updated post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved:

```
Pkg.rm("Compat")

Pkg.update()

Pkg.add("Compat")
 
Pkg.build("GR")
```

Comment: Hi, you can accept your own answer as the solution, in order to mark this as a resolved question.